# Can ASP.NET sql membership feed a SAML identity provider?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, saml, auth0

I have an ASP.NET Web API (v4, specifically) application that currently authenticates using Forms authentication (through a SQL membership provider (i.e. using aspnet_Membership, aspnet_Users tables and all that)). It's basically the backend API hub for a bunch of other applications.

Alongside that, I have a third-party application, SP (for service provider), which supports SSO and single logout using SAML. My goal is to set up a SAML identity provider that can receive a SAML single logout request, which would in turn send a logout response to SP.

I started out looking at [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/protocols/saml/saml-configuration) to achieve this, but I am confused about what role Auth0 would actually play as the identity provider since all of my user creds are stored in my own database. Is there some way I can supply Auth0 (or any of these identity providers) with my user creds store for it to authenticate my users? Or is this not desirable/possible and I need to make my existing app to be the SAML identity provider?

Answer (score 0):

To use SAML in your client application, you need a [SAML stack](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

So you could add the stack and it would be self-contained.

Both [identityserver](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/reference/aspnet_identity.html) and [Auth0](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/custom-db) can use a SQL DB as the authentication store. They both support the SAML protocol.

Once you have done the SAML configuration, you just need e.g. a login screen where the users decides local authentication or SAML authentication (this invokes the IDP and that would do the SAML side for you).